# redirect to url on clicking in td space 

Tags: html

is there any way when to go to URL when user click in `<td>`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
<td><a href="http://example.com">&nbsp;</a></td>
```

or

```
<td onclick="window.location='http://example.com'"></td>
```

Answer (score 6):

**for same window**

```
onclick="window.location('www.example.com')"
```

**for new window**

```
onclick="window.open('www.example.com')";
```

Answer (score 5):

Bind a Javascript method to the onclick event on the TD,  if you are using jQuery you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("td").click(function(){

    // Perform your action on click here, like redirecting to a new url
    window.location='http://google.com';
});

});
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to have any other `element` in your `td` then you can do it this way:

```
<td onclick="javascript:window.location.href-'http://www.stackoverflow.com'" style="cursor:hand">Stackoverflow</td>
```

Answer (score 3):

either fill the td with an `<a>` or set it's `onclick` to `window.location = "URL"`

Comment: can you describe full code for onclick , is there any way to change mouse cursor to hand ?

Comment: you can change the cursor with css.  Such as `td { cursor:pointer; }`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTd').click(function(){
        window.location= "http://google.com";
    });
});
```

demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/zainshaikh/4acMG/3/

Answer (score 2):

Some of these answers provide javascript. Please always include a normal (anchor tag) link for visitors who don't have javascript active in their browser.

Answer (score -1):

There are three ways you can do so.

1) `<td><a href="http://example.com">Click me</a></td>`

2) `<a href="http://example.com"><td>Click me</td></a>`

3) `<td onclick="window.location='http://example.com'"></td>`

Comment: What about a click event handler?  Number 2 is not valid HTML.  This answer is inaccurate, implies exclusivity, and does not provide explanation for the examples.