# Clickable Site - Working table Hyperlink

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, hyperlink

I need to make all site clickable.
I tried to make *ahref* before content *div* but it works only in Firefox&Chrome not in IE.
So I made site as a clickable table like this:

```
 <table onclick="window.location='http://google.pl'" id="Table_01"> ...here goes content...
```

It's working in Chrome, FireFox and IE ....but... I am wondering if it is right method and it will be working on every computer?

Comment: Why don't you just use nested <a> tags?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182487/redirect-to-url-on-clicking-in-td-space

Comment: because <a> tags outside a block tag like table didn't work in IE

Comment: @Adam which version of IE are you using?

Comment: @VivecVelothian I use IE 8

Answer (score 1):

According html5 spec, you can use link tag  outside a block tag like table:

```
<a href="http://google.pl">
    <table></table>
</a>
```

Dont forget to apply display: block to link.

If you dont want to use link tag, you should write your script on js file and not usinf onclick property using id for example:

```
<table id="Table_01">
```

js:

```
function redirect() {
    window.location = 'http://google.pl';
}
document.getElementById("Table_01").onclick = redirect;
```