# The href in template and the Url are not working in Django

Tags: javascript, html, url, onclick, href

I am new to django. I have made a table cell clickable but when i click that cell, nothing happens.

`template` :

```
 {% for each in object_list %}
   <tr>                  
   <td id="{{ each.id }}"   data-href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/{{ each.region }}/{{ each.id }}"></td>
   </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

needed part of `view`:

```
class MeterDetailView(DetailView):
       model = Meter
       template_name = 'meter/specificMeter.html'

       def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
          pk = kwargs.get('pk',None)
          obj = Meter.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

`url` :

```
    path('<int:region>/<int:pk>/', views.MeterDetailView.as_view(), name='detail')
```

`model` :

```
class Meter(models.Model):
   region   = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
   UserId   = models.BigIntegerField(default=0,null=False)
```

what is wrong?Thank you all.

Comment: What is `each`? Can you provide the corresponding model?

Comment: Did you by the way include the javascript for the `data-href`? It looks like this is something built on top of jQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17147973/67579

Comment: I added my model.I did not include js for href.@WillemVanOnsem

Comment: well then this will not work, since `data-href` in itself is not something to make the column a link. The JavaScript will basically turn the cells in the row into clicable items by manipulating the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make the cell that redirects after it's clicked you can use `onclick` attribute. In your case we would have to change the code a bit:

```
 {% for each in object_list %}
   <tr>                  
       <td id="{{ each.id }}" onclick="window.location='http://127.0.0.1:8000/{{ each.region }}/{{ each.id}}'"></td>
   </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

similar approaches can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182487/redirect-to-url-on-clicking-in-td-space) question

Comment: please upvote the answer if it was helpful to you so others see is as a valid solution if they have similar problem :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to specify url you should use as folows:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [ 
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('',YourView, name='UseForSpecifyUrl'),]
```

.html

```
<div class="col-6 text-right">
<a href="{% url 'UseForSpecifyUrl' %}" class="text-primary"><small>Do something</small></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like it's already explained in the comments under your question, `data-href` is just a variant of the `dataset` HTML property. You can read about it more here: [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset.)

The easiest approach: insert all your cell data inside `<a href="link"></a>` tag. [This question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326426/making-a-td-clickable) selected answer can tell you more.

It's also possible to do with `data-href` by adding an `onclick` event to your code:

```
<td id="{{ each.id }}" data-href="{% url 'detail' each.region each.id %}" onclick="makeCellClickable()" class="some-class></td>
```

Notice that I've put an `url` tag instead of a direct link as a data-href.

Other that that, you need to specify `makeCellClickable()` function in your linked js file or in html file within `<script></script>` tag. Don't forget to add a class like `some-class` to your stylesheet that would change background, cursor or however you want to show users that cell is clickable.

```
function makeCellClickable() {
    window.location = this.event.target.dataset.href
}
```